# Rails: parse weirdly-formatted JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My JSON response from an external service looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/lead/2231\"},\"Id\":\"2231\",\"FirstName\":\"Jean\"}"=>nil, "external_id"=>"2231"}
```

How can I parse the `Id` and `FirstName` keys in Rails 5? I've tried everything. I know Rails 5 has the .`to_unsafe_h` method, that's not my problem. It's more the weird nested formatting that has a value of `nil` after `"Jean"` above.

Comment: Why do you have `Parameters`? Does the external service make a request to your rails server?

Comment: According to http://jsonlint.com/ your JSON is not valid JSON, so I don't see how it can be parsed at all without doing it manually

Comment: That's exactly [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please tell us how you got this response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pay attention closely, you will see:

`"{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Lead\",\"url\":\"/services/lead/2231\"},\"Id\":\"2231\",\"FirstName\":\"Jean\"}"` is actually a string, a key, and the value value associated to it is `nil`.

If you want to parse that, just can use `parameters.keys[0].to_json`; although I will double check first why you are getting the parameters in that incorrect state in the first place.